# subquery that starts with "with" in teradata is not working

Tags: teradata

I have a query (that I cannot modify) that starts like this

```
with CodeSet (
   code_context_c
 , bom_index_c
 , src_qs_c
 , src_code_set_c 
 , src_code_set_x 
 , src_code_value_c
 , src_code_value_x
 , tgt_code_set_c
 , tgt_code_value_c
  ) as (
SELECT ...
```

and then goes on. Now I need to use it as a subquery and do something like

```
select * from (with CodeSet (
       code_context_c
     , bom_index_c
     , src_qs_c
     , src_code_set_c 
     , src_code_set_x 
     , src_code_value_c
     , src_code_value_x
     , tgt_code_set_c
     , tgt_code_value_c
      ) as (
    SELECT ...
```

but Teradata does not like it... Anyone has seen this before? Changing the query would require some time and I would prefer not to. Anyone can help me out here?

Error message is:

SELECT Failed.  [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or '(' between the 'from' keyword and the 'as' keyword.

Thanks in advance,
Umberto

Comment: It is quite likely that this feature is not supported by Teradata (by the way, you haven't mentioned which version you are using) according to this:http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/use-of-cte-within-stored-procedures You may refer to TD 14 documentation with regards to `WITH` here: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.072.html#ww10763668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer, but you need to run the SELECT after your WITH statement.  WITH doesn't actually materialize a table until you SELECT from it.  So something like this:

```
;WITH CodeSet (
      blah
      , blah
      , ...
    ) AS (
    SELECT  blah
            , blah
            , ...
    )
    ;
    SELECT * FROM CodeSet;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciated it.